# using interactive_output in ipywidgets to manage the layout of multiple input widgets to create a more user-friendly interface

Tags: python, ipywidgets

Working on an interactive viz in Jupyter notebboks and get an attribution error, I tried upgrading widgets, didn't work.

```
    import ipywidgets as widgets
    from ipywidgets import interact
    one = widgets.IntSlider(min=0,          max =10)
    two = widgets.IntSlider(min=0, max=100)
    three = widgets.IntSlider(min=0, max=1000)
    ui = widgets.Hbox([one,two,three] ` ` `
                    
---->`AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
 C:\Users\LARRYD~1\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_16808/2257911237.py in <module>
  4 two = widgets.IntSlider(min=0, max=100)
  5 three = widgets.IntSlider(min=0, max=1000)
----> 6 ui = widgets.Hbox([one,two,three])

 AttributeError: module 'ipywidgets' has no attribute 'Hbox'

 def func(x,y,z):
 print (f"The first value is: {x+2}")
 print(f"The second value is: {y*2}")
 print(f"The third value is {z**2}")
 out = widgets.interactive_output(func, {'x': one, 'y' : two, 'z':
 tree}) display(ui, out)


 NameError: name 'ui' is not defined
```

Answer (score 2):

You've got a typo in the widget name. You need a capital `B`, it's called `HBox` not `Hbox`

You've also got a typo later when you call `widgets.interactive_output`. Change `tree` to `three`.

try:

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
from ipywidgets import interact
one = widgets.IntSlider(min=0, max=10)
two = widgets.IntSlider(min=0, max=100)
three = widgets.IntSlider(min=0, max=1000)
ui = widgets.HBox([one,two,three])               

def func(x,y,z):
    print (f"The first value is: {x+2}")
    print(f"The second value is: {y*2}")
    print(f"The third value is {z**2}")

out = widgets.interactive_output(func, {'x': one, 'y' : two, 'z': three}) 

display(ui, out)
```